# What is the best way to send real-time data between apps without latency

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In Android, I have a background application that is gathering some sensing data, processing it and sending it as intent to a Unity application running in the foreground, which uses it to update the transform of an object. As you might guess, I need to do this 60 times a second. Using the intent as a way of communicating between the apps really adds latency and sluggishness to the transformations in Unity. Is there a better way to do real-time communication between two Android apps? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the type of data. What data are you sending?

Comment: Hi I'm just sending a json object with a simulated Android Motion event and a quaternion value. It should be just a few bytes.

Comment: TCP should be fine

Answer (score 2):

If you can use AIDL Remote callbacks you can do that with very low latency.

https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Android/Android%20Programming_%20Pushing%20the%20Limits%20%5BHellman%202013-11-04%5D.pdf

Page number 141 aidl callbacks explains about this.

In my case i was using 1500 per second frequency so it still works in a non-blocking fashion.

Comment: Hi, I followed your example and built 2 android applications using AIDL to communicate with almost 1ms latency. Although this looks promising, I'm struggling to carry this knowledge over to the Unity side. Do you know of resources that demonstrate how to use AIDL callbacks on the Unity front?

Comment: https://github.com/lcbasu/android/blob/master/adt/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.java.                                                                    
                                                                                                                          I Guess this link should be helpful. Try to debug this

Answer (score 1):

If the time is most of what you concerned, you should use either TCP or UDP. However, base on what kind of app you are making, UDP and TCP may function differently:

[What is the difference between TCP and UDP?](https://support.holmsecurity.com/hc/en-us/articles/212963869-What-is-the-difference-between-TCP-and-UDP-)

Comment: Hello, I finally implemented a UDP communication between my background app and the Unity app. I tried 2 different approaches: a) UDP on the C# side b) UDP in Java in an Android plugin within Unity. With both cases I am getting so much latency. I'm pretty surprised UDP would cause latency considering it would discard packets, but this is what I'm experiencing. Any tips on how to procedd?

Comment: @ArunYogannadan Hi there, although UDP is faster than TCP because it doesn't expect the response, yet you still need to optimize the package you sent. A larger package will cause more lag for sure.

Answer (score -1):

You cant send data without latency.Yes here is just a great solution for me ,Google play games(Google real time multiplayer), Its mainly room based max 8 player , its making peer to peer connection and you can send TCP and UDP messages . But times per second saying that you are sending your messages from FixedUpdate function.I will advise you not send too fast ,send like 1 message every 4 frame (depends how you will do your network synchronization),TCP may stack and you will never get wanted result.UDP is more effective and connectionless protocol and message may be delivered and  may not.Anyway you must do some network synchronization.